# Extract http status code from the log result in Splunk

Tags: java, regex, splunk

I am using the following Splunk query to get all the response content and their corresponding response status code.

`index=main env=nonprod sourcetype="*sample-service*" "response"`

Sample response log from the above Splunk query looks like:

`||INFO||||Response:{"requestId:"369018b6-0fd4-11ee-be56-0242ac120002","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"url":"https://sample-service.abcCompany.com","statusCode":200,"method":"POST","timeTaken":98,"body":{"..":"..","...":"..."}}`

I am trying to extract the `statusCode` as a field so that I can see the number of occurrences of each http statusCode from the service response.

Here is the regular expression I tried to extract statusCode:
`"statusCode":([\d]*)`

I tried using above regular expression in the Splunk query:
`index=main env=nonprod sourcetype="*sample-service*" "response" | rex "statusCode":([\d]*)`

But got Error in the search parser:
`Error in 'SearchParser': Missing a search command before '\'.`
Not sure how to implement this to extract the statusCode field so that I can visualize the number of occurrences of each statusCode.

My expected result sample is:

| statusCode | count |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 5000 |
| 404 | 4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your regular expression `"statusCode":([\d]*)` is correct to capture the statusCode, I think it would work if you put escape characters for `"` and specify a named group.

So, the regex would be: `\"statusCode\":(?<statusCode>[\d]*)`

So, the final Splunk query would look like:

```
index=main env=nonprod sourcetype="*sample-service*" "response" 
| rex "\"statusCode\":(?<statusCode>[\d]*)" 
| stats count by statusCode
```

Demo for regex match and named capture group:
https://regex101.com/r/UWdib7/1

Comment: Even simpler (and 2x as efficient): `| rex "statusCode\D+(?<statusCodeValue>[\d]+)"`

Comment: @warren I agree, we can avoid initial `"` and directly start from `statusCode`. Did you mean that using `\D+`  instead of `\":` is more efficient?

Comment: yes - your regex takes 69 steps. Mine is 32 :) https://regex101.com/r/MdAxWN/1

Comment: actually just 33 if initial `"` is skipped. Thanks for the insight.